XMLGET to get third level inner tag removed and have other innermost nested tags in snowflake
Below is my XML data
<Report>
<Inquiries>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>57</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>INC.</MemberName>
    <Date>30</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>53</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>CO.</MemberName>
    <Date>10</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>49</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>VE</MemberName>
    <Date>13</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>39</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>DESJA</MemberName>
    <Date>09</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>54</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>DA</MemberName>
    <Date>21</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>82</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>LOANS</MemberName>
    <Date>17</Date>
  </Inquiry>
</Inquiries>

**I want only the all tags under  like below **
<MemberCode>57</MemberCode>
<MemberName>INC.</MemberName>
<Date>30</Date>

1.Below is the snowflake query used to determine column values.
    SELECT  top 100
                KEY,
                b.VALUE
                ,b.this
                
                ,GET(XMLGET(XML_DATA,'Report'),'$')::string as first_level
                ,XMLGET(XMLGET(XML_DATA,'Report'),'Inquiries') as second_level
                ,XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(XML_DATA,'Report'),'Inquiries'),'Inquiry') as third_level
                
               ,GET(b.VALUE,'@')::STRING as name
            ,CONCAT(XMLGET(b.VALUE,'MemberCode'):"$",
            XMLGET(b.VALUE,'MemberName'):"$",
            XMLGET(b.VALUE,'Date'):"$") AS MAIN_VALUE,
            
            from
                 FULL_XML,
                LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET(XMLGET(XML_DATA,'Report'),'Inquiries'):"$") b;

2.With above query I get same value for both second_level and third_level. Need Help in getting only tags under 

with data_in_cte as (
    select parse_xml('<Report>
<Inquiries>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>57</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>INC.</MemberName>
    <Date>30</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>53</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>CO.</MemberName>
    <Date>10</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>49</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>VE</MemberName>
    <Date>13</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>39</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>DESJA</MemberName>
    <Date>09</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>54</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>DA</MemberName>
    <Date>21</Date>
  </Inquiry>
  <Inquiry>
    <MemberCode>82</MemberCode>
    <MemberName>LOANS</MemberName>
    <Date>17</Date>
  </Inquiry>
</Inquiries>
</Report>') as XML_DATA
)
select
 get(xmlget(i.value,'MemberCode'),'$')::text as a,
 get(xmlget(i.value,'MemberName'),'$')::text as b,
 get(xmlget(i.value,'Date'),'$')::text as  c,
 a || b || c as result
from data_in_cte
,table(flatten(input=>xmlget(xml_data,'Inquiries')['$'])) as i

gives what I beleive you are asking for, (based off your prior question):

Just the sub-objects:
select
 xmlget(i.value,'MemberCode') as a,
 xmlget(i.value,'MemberName') as b,
 xmlget(i.value,'Date') as  c,

from data_in_cte
,table(flatten(input=>xmlget(xml_data,'Inquiries')['$'])) as i

gives the sub-objects, but not as one column, because "many object in need to go inside a single root object":


Thanks Simeon, I need column to have these XMLtag exluding outer tag 57
INC.
30

@gayathri so you want an "xml object" without the sub-objects being in an object?
